# Prevent Cross site scripting attack in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, eval, xss, checkmarx

Below is the code for which I got checkmarx report stating that its vulnerable to stored XSS.it says the data layer gets data from the database, for the dt element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being
properly filtered or encoded and is eventually displayed to the user in aspx page.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
 OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_OnRowDeleting"  OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" Width ="1000px" class="grid">
 <Columns>   
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Name">   
        <ItemTemplate>   
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Uname") %>'></asp:Label>   
        </ItemTemplate>   
        <EditItemTemplate>   
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Uname") %>'></asp:TextBox>   //this is the line vulnerable to XSS
        </EditItemTemplate>   
    </asp:TemplateField>       
</Columns>
```

code behind

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Uid,Uname,Utype,Uemail,ClientName,ProjectName,Ulog from usrtable where ClientName=@clientname and Utype=@Normal, con);
  adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientname", clientname); 
 adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Normal", "Normal");        
   adapt.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
    } 



if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Should I encode all the column values which am passing to item template or is it any other line of code vulnerable. If its html encoding, how do I achieve it. Kindly guide me through this issue.

Comment: don't string concat your sql query!

Comment: @DanielA.White you forgot this https://xkcd.com/327/ ;-)

Comment: Type the following into your text box `Liam OR 1=1`.... :O

Comment: @Liam, wrong typed! `Liam ' or 1 = 1 --`

Comment: @bradbury9 yes... :)

Comment: I have edited it and have made it parameterized query. This is SQL injection. I am facing stored XSS risk too. Which part of the code is vulnerable to XSS

Comment: You missed one... `and Utype='Admin' or ClientName='" + clientname + "'and 1`

Comment: @Liam , its done

Comment: I'm guessing `clientname` gets read out of a querystring and `ClientName` (SQL) is then displayed on the front page? If this is true, you don't have an XSS vulnerability. It just looks like you do. Querying the DB essentially sanitises the variable for you. You do have a SQL injection vulnerability, adding the parameters is essential here as you are opening up your entire DB to exploitation

Comment: Also, you still haven't... `nd Utype='Admin' or ClientName='" + clientname + "'and Utype=@Normal` **Do not append SQL, at all, ever**. Especially if the variables are read directly from the querystring, form, etc.

Comment: @Liam yes am binding the datatable to gridview in the UI. In the checkmarx report the below two lines of code was shown as vulnerable to XSS. This is what is bothering me <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Uname") %>'></asp:TextBox> and adapt.Fill(dt);Will this lead to XSS

Comment: Tl;Dr Type a value (something nonesense like `xxx`) into the querystring where you read `clientname`. Does this appear anywhere? if it does, stop this.

Comment: I am not passing it as querystring. it is supplied by user in add user page. Client name is a textbox

Comment: @Liam, that is wrong - querying the DB does not ever sanitise the variable for you, it just pushes the vector to the database instead of the URL. This is known as Stored XSS, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Can you provide me a code example on how to proceed with it.what should I do to eliminate XSS risk

Answer (score 1):

To prevent XSS when using TemplateField on .NET Frameworks 4.0 or older I use [Microsoft Web Protection Library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) on the aspx page. 
On .NET Framework 4.5 is already integrate on the Frameworks there is no more need for library.

Frameworks 4.0 or older.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" 
     Text='<%#Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString()) %>'> 
</asp:Label>
```

Frameworks 4.5

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" 
     Text='<%#System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString(),true) %>'> 
</asp:Label>
```

This will encode your label when they rendered. Use it only for the ItemTemplate, EditItemTemplate render has html input text and it will be encoded by the framework by default.

Comment: Note that the library explicitly says in its homepage that it's in its end of life and it was included in the framework itself.

Comment: You are actually right, thanks for point it out. I edited my answer.

Answer (score -3):

To prevent the XSS you could add a server side CustomValidator (to prevent javascript validation bypass) associated with the textbox and setup the domain logic.

Edit (OP edited): <del>You would also want to use parametrized queries to avoid SQL errors (user introducing single quotes and breaking the SQL) **and SQL Injection**.</del>

Edit: The validator should check for malicious/unallowed html/js/css code. Not an expert on XSS, but you can have a look at OWAS for good guidelines. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Needs more details.

Comment: What should the custom validator do?

Comment: @Liam edited trying to explaing what the CustomValidator should check IMHO (im not much into XSS tho) and linking to OWASP for a nice reference.

Comment: I went through all articles but for my scenario I dint find anything. so asked a question here.